# check if value exists

Tags: php, recursion

I am working in code igniter,

code igniter has a function called table_exists();

where you pass it a table name, and, as expected it checks the database to see if it exists.

What I want to do is,

start with tablename

if tablename exists, use tablename1, if tablename1 exists use tablename2 etc.

My question is,

what is the best way to write this?

Comment: This smells like a terrible idea! In fact, it smells just like [this one](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Confessions-The-Shopping-Cart.aspx). What in the world do you want to use this for?

Comment: @deceze: very true, However, How else would you store the contents of these CSV files (must be in mysql for indexing) where the only solid fact about them is that they all have a mobile column with a standard format, it can have an arbitrary amount of columns with an arbitrary amount of rows. they can (with no exaggeration) range from a one row, 35 column csv to a 80k row 1 column csv... I am open to other ideas.

Comment: There are many solutions for this, from attribute-value schemas to JSON storage and NoSQL storage. Open a new question about it. Whatever you do though, don't dynamically create tables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 1;
$table_name = 'table';
$table_name_test = $table_name;

while($this->db->table_exists($table_name_test)) {
    $table_name_test = $table_name . strval($i);
    $i++;
}

$tablename = $tablename_test;
```

Make sure you use the full `$this->db->table_exists()` CodeIgniter syntax

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
$tblname = "sometablename";
$i = 1;
$new_tblname = $tblname;
while ($this->db->table_exists($new_tblname)){
  $new_tblname = $tblname . $i++;
}
echo $new_tblname;
```